# Curl not working for HTTP Post to Spring-data-rest RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, curl, spring-restcontroller

I have a `RequestMapping` setup in a spring `@Controller` and I am unable to correctly send a CURL request to it.  I keep getting a `HTTP 400` return code when trying to send various ways.  I am not sure what is setup incorrectly.

Here is the request

```
curl -v -X POST localhost:8082/api/registerDevice -d '{"serial":"FA541YJ05065"}' -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Here is the output

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8082 (#0)
> POST /api/registerDevice HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8082
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 23
>
* upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 16 Jun 2016 02:48:50 GMT
< Connection: close
<
{"timestamp":1466045330556,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3bae0839; line: 1, column: 2]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3bae0839; line: 1, column: 2]","path":"/api/registerDevice"}* Closing connection 0
```

**Spring RequestMapping**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "registerDevice", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<String> registerDevice(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) throws Exception {
```

**Update**

As mentioned below it was an issue with escaping the quotes and related to windows.  The same CURL command worked fine on centos.

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""serial""":"""FA541YJ05065"""}" http://localhost:8082/api/deregisterDevice
```

On Centos

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"serial":"FA541YJ05065"}' http://localhost:8082/api/registerDevice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you end up sending `'` at the start of the json. You can try using double quotes around the json and escaping them in it.
[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

```
curl -v -X POST localhost:8082/api/registerDevice -d "{\"serial\":\"FA541YJ05065\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Yes it turns out the issue was on Windows.  It works fine on our centos system but windows was requiring the data to be escaped.

curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""serial""":"""FA541YJ05065"""}" http://localhost:8082/api/deregisterDevice

On Centos

curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"serial":"FA541YJ05065"}' http://localhost:8082/api/registerDevice

Answer (score 0):

The only reason behind this is that fact that your request is not formatted correctly
Check out this [Spring 4.x/3.x (Web MVC) REST API and JSON2 Post requests, how to get it right once for all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909742/spring-4-x-3-x-web-mvc-rest-api-and-json2-post-requests-how-to-get-it-right-o?lq=1) for more information.